# How to debug cuke4duke using ant and attaching a remote debugger

Tags: debugging, ant, cucumber

Following the cuke4duke ant tutorial at http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_ant.html, it supplies the following to run the cuke4duke task:

```
<taskdef name="cucumber" classname="cuke4duke.ant.CucumberTask" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
<cucumber args="--verbose --require target/test-classes --color --format pretty --format junit --out target/junit-report features" objectFactory="pico">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="target/test-classes"/>
  </classpath>
</cucumber>
```

To debug, according to https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/wiki/Debug-Cuke4Duke-Steps you just add the following jvm arguments:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000
```

However, it doesn't actually specify how to do this in ant, and because this isn't a normal java ant task, I have no idea how these arguments are supposed to be added.  Does anyone else know?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how findbugs works, apparently you can append the jvm arguments to the cucumber task:

```
<cucumber args="--verbose --require target/test-classes --color --format pretty --format junit --out target/junit-report features" objectFactory="pico" jvmargs="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000">
```

The cucumber task will break and wait for a remote debugging connection on port 4000, allowing you to debug the code through an IDE such as Eclipse.